# How to create contact approval history

Tags: apex, approval-process, customer-portal

When the portal users are registered successfully, in that situation user is add to contact of particular account. Here Account owner is changed(not Admin user, we need to change manager user),In that contact Approval is awaiting for Manager user.when manager is accept that approval we need to create Approval History automatically. Please give me examples

Comment: Approval history for objects are created automatically. For example if your approval process is on Account object, then Edit layout of Account and add Approval History related list to page. Then you can see history. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Hi  abdn,  Already add to the approval history from  edit layout. But it can't show the any results.